# AnyLogic convert String to Node

Tags: java, anylogic

Can somebody help me convert from `String` to `Node`?

The problem is, when I load data from `database`, I cannot convert the `varchar` datatype to `Node` or `INode`.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: i can also not convert apple to oranges... but you probably don't want to convert a string to a node... you want something else not stated in your question

Comment: I have a database where I have a `varchar` column called 'tarhely'. On my Graphical editor I have a few `Rectangular node` which has the same name as the values in the 'tarhely' column of the database. I want to send my `Agent` to the `Rectangular node` where the values are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send your agent to a rectangular node which name is the same as your value in the database...

```
String theName=selectFrom(db_table)
.firstResult(db_table.tarhely);//let's assume this gets you the name of the node
Node rect=findFirst(network.nodes(), n->n.getName().equals(theName)); //this will get you the node
```

network.nodes() will get you all the nodes existing in the network... be careful to select the correct network of nodes if you have many... then you get the first node that matches the name with findFirst..